# Prefered field searching in lucene

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I have an index and I want to search it on multiple fields. I am working on Query Builder for this application wherein I want to give more preference to a certain field than others.

Let's say the fields are: `RollNo, Name, Age`

In this case, when someone searches with `RollNo` field along with `Name`, I want to give preference to results which come from `RollNo` matching.

Anybody knows how to do this in Lucene. I am using Lucene 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Query.setBoost()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html#setBoost%28float%29) method to boost during query time.

Check boosting part of [this](http://blog.architexa.com/2010/12/custom-lucene-scoring/) document for more information.